# In a family with two children, what are the chances, if the oldest child is a girl, that both children are girls?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If $X$ is the random variable representing the number of girls out of 2 children. The probability to get a child of a given sex rahter than the other is 1/2. X equals 0 with probability 1/4, 1 with probability 1/2, and 2 with probability 1/4.

We can define a new random variable $Z$ the number of girls conditional on the older child being a girl. According to [this book (p. 73)](http://backspaces.net/temp/Ebooks/DataScienceFromScratch/Data_Science_from_Scratch.pdf), when $Z = 1$ the probability is 1/2 and 2 with probability 1/2.

However, when I compute it :

$$\frac{\overbrace{1/2}^{probability \ of \ [the \ number \ of \ girls = 1]}}{\underbrace{1/2}_{probability \ of \ the \ older \ child \ being \ a \ girl}} = 1$$

What do I get wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional probability.
$$
P(R|S) = \frac{P(R\cap S)}{P(S)}
$$
Here $R$ is "both children are girls" and $S$ is "the oldest child is a girl".

Let's take sample space consisting of four items:
$$
(G,G),\quad(G,B),\quad (B,G),\quad (B,B)
$$
each with probability $1/4$.  Then
$$
R = \{(G,G)\}
\\
S = \{(G,G),(G,B)\}
\\
R\cap S = \{(G,G)\}
$$
and therefore
$$
P(R|S) = \frac{P(R\cap S)}{P(S)} = \frac{\;1/4\;}{1/2} = \frac{1}{2} .
$$

Comment: Also: Given knowledge that the *older* child is a girl, then you will have the event that both children are girls, when you find that the *younger* child is a girl too.$$\mathbb P(\textsf{both are girls}\mid \textsf{older is a girl})~{=\mathbb P(\textsf{younger is a girl})\\=\frac 12}$$

Answer (score 0):

> We can define a new random variable $Z$ the number of girls conditional on the older child being a girl.

**No we cannot.**  Disregard the book; it is incoherent.  Random variables are not defined as conditional; it is the *probability measures* that are defined as such.

What we can define is the random variable $Y$ as indicating that the older child is a girl ($0$ if not, $1$ if so).  Then we have the conditional probability measures for $X$ under the condition $Y=1$: $$\mathsf P(X=x\mid Y=1)=\begin{cases}\tfrac 12 &:& x=1 \text{ or }x=2\\[1ex]0&:&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

---

Thus is defined as $$\mathsf P(X=x\mid Y=1)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X-Y=x-1\cap Y=1)}{\mathsf P(Y=1)}\\=\mathsf P(X-Y=x-1)$$